# Integrating infinitesimal transformations in CFT

Tags: group-theory, conformal-field-theory, lie-algebra, complex-numbers, classical-field-theory

Consider a conformal transformation $z\mapsto f(z)$ of the complex plane described infinitesimally by the vector field $X\partial+\bar{X}\bar{\partial}$. I was wondering how one can, starting from the infinitesimal form
$$\tilde{\phi}(\tilde{z})=\phi(z)-(\epsilon h\partial X+\epsilon\bar{h}\bar{\partial}\bar{X})\phi(z),$$
for the transformation of the field $\phi$ one can obtain the global form
$$\tilde{\phi}(\tilde{z})=(\partial f)^{-h}(\bar{\partial}\bar{f})^{-\bar{h}}\phi(z).$$
While I can see how this must be true, for the latter reduces to the former when $f(z)=z+\epsilon X$ and the latter satisfies the group law, I would like to know if there is a direct way.

My attempt so far is the following. For a global transformation the field $\tilde{\phi}$ is defined by $\tilde{\phi}=\phi_1,$ where
$$\frac{d\phi_t(z_t)}{dt}=-(h\partial X(z_t)+\bar{h}\bar{\partial}\bar{X}(z_t))\phi_t(z_t)\text{, where }\phi_0=\phi.$$
In here $z_t$ is similarly defined by
$$\frac{dz_t}{dt}=X(z_t)\text{, where }z_0=z.$$
In particular $f(z)=z_1$. Now, this equation would seem to have the simple solution
$$\tilde{\phi}(\tilde{z})=e^{-\int_0^1dt(h\partial X(z_t)+\bar{h}\bar{\partial}\bar{X}(z_t))}\phi(z).$$
Thus the result would be obtain if one showed that
$$e^{\int_0^1dt\partial X(z_t)}=\partial f(z).$$
This feels off, for
$$e^{\int_0^1dt\partial X(z_t)}=e^{\int_0^1dt\frac{\frac{dX(z_t)}{dt}}{\frac{dz_t}{dt}}}=e^{\int_0^1dt\frac{\frac{dX(z_t)}{dt}}{X(z_t)}}=e^{\int_0^1dt\frac{d\ln X(z_t)}{dt}}=\frac{X(f(z))}{X(z)}$$